# Connection String Issue with nested grid view Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio-2015

Receiving an error saying the connectionstring is not found or empty.

Am I using the proper connection string ID? I'm lost right now and am just trying everything I can think of.

.Config Connection strings:

```
     <connectionStrings>
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=&quot;|DataDirectory|\aspnet-HUTDMS V-2.0-20160808082503.mdf&quot;;Initial Catalog=&quot;aspnet-HUTDMS V-2.0-20160808082503&quot;;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="HUTDMSConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\HUTDMS.mdf;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
     </connectionStrings>
```

Below is my aspx page showing the 2 spots where I need to list an "SqlDataSource" in this case its HUTDMSConnectionString. This is where I'm unsure if HUTDMSConnectionString is right.

```
AllowPaging="True"
AutoGenerateColumns="False"
DataKeyNames="CustomerID"
DataSourceID="HUTDMSConnectionString"
PageSize="20"
OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound"
CellPadding="4"
ForeColor="#333333"
GridLines="None" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">



<asp:SqlDataSource ID="HUTDMSConnectionString" runat="server"
ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\HUTDMS.mdf;Integrated Security=True %>"
SelectCommand="SELECT [CourseID], [BookTitle], [Ancillary], [BookActive],[ActiveDate], [InactiveDate], [Author], [Imprint], [Publisher], [EditionAndDate], 
[tenISBN], [VendorISBN], [ebookAvailable], [eISBN], [Notes] FROM [textBooks]" OnSelecting="SqlDataSource2_Selecting">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: Look at your data source. You have put the contents of the connection string in there, not the name of the connection string. Kind of defeats the purpose if you have to repeat the connection data don't you think?

Comment: I'm confused, I dont know what to put in the SqlDataSource ID="" spot. Do I put "Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\HUTDMS.mdf;Integrated Security=True"  ??

Comment: No of course not. That would defeat the purpose of using the config file if you have to repeat it. You can do this two ways. You can either keep guessing at the string or you can use the UI to make this a lot easier. Since you seem to be pretty new to this I would suggest the UI. Go to the properties of your SqlDataSource and choose the connection string from the dropdown.

Comment: I've done that, that was the first thing I tried. It is "SqlDataSource2" so I placed that in both positions and still gotten nothing

Comment: The problem is where you have ConnectionString. You want to use the NAME property from your config file, not the value for connection string.